# How to override styles in SharePoint

Tags: 2010, branding, sharepoint-enterprise

I currently am using a custom `LI` style to present images of YouTube clips.  The style seems to be working as intended. The issue is that SharePoint is also applying a bullet on the side of each image in the list. I presume there is a style I need to override. How would I go about overriding this so I only see my intended style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you have an UL/OL tag with a custom CSS class.

If you do something like this, it should kill the bullets:

`ul.YOURCLASS { list-style-type: none; }`

Comment: I do.  I have a UL wrapped around the LI's that are using a custom class.  I will give this a try.

Answer (score -1):

See this http://css-tricks.com/2708-override-inline-styles-with-css/
Use this "!important;"
Hope that helps
Patrick

Comment: I will continue to down vote suggestions to use !important. If you write accurate and correct markup, and have the prioritization correct, !important is not needed. The use of this attribute is a bad practice in every element of web design/development, not just SharePoint. It is so frustrating to see this "solution" continuing to be offered. It is a shortcut solution to learning how CSS priorities are determined.

Comment: webdes03 i don't need to write CSS very often.Can you send me a post or an article i can read from you to explain the reason to stop this habit?

Comment: Sure, I wrote this one the other day: http://mike-greene.com/2011/10/custom-css-and-sharepoint-branding-the-right-way/. A quick internet search should yield some good results too, including this post: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2010/11/02/the-important-css-declaration-how-and-when-to-use-it/.